# Custom image shuffler not working?

Tags: javascript

Basically, what I'm trying to do is shuffle through images using some JavaScript code. All it does is change the display style of the current image to `block`, and at the same time change the previous one to `none`.

The HTML code:

```
<body>
<img src="http://bit.ly/yOqqbg" id="image1" style="display: block;">
<img src="http://bit.ly/dezBUZ" id="image2" style="display: none;">
<img src="http://bit.ly/IvM5HE" id="image3" style="display: none;">
</body>​
```

The JavaScript code:

```
var id = ["image1", "image2", "image3"]; //Array with the id's in the document you want        
to shuffle through
var i = 0; //Set inital array element
initiateTimer(); //Get the loop going

function initiateTimer() {       
if (i > id.length) {
    i = 0;
    initiateTimer();
}
setTimeout(function() { changeElement(); }, 2000); //2000 = 2 seconds
}

function changeElement() {  
if (id === 0) {
    document.getElementById(id[2]).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(id[i]).style.display = 'block';
} else {
    document.getElementById(id[i - 1]).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(id[i]).style.display = 'block';
}
i += 1;
initiateTimer();
} ​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when `i === 3` you will have problems

```
if (i > id.length) {
```

should become

```
if (i >= id.length) {
```

UPDATE: http://jsfiddle.net/HgNuc/

Comment: Thank you, however, that's not the current problem. Currently, the issue is that it doesn't run at all. Nothing happens.

Comment: move `initiateTimer(); //Get the loop going` to the bottom of the script, it's in scope but not assigned at the point you call it

Comment: Thank you for that tip, but still no luck.

Comment: you know what, the problem is right here: `if (id === 0) {` that should be `if (i === 0) {`